# O que é pool de conexões em Banco de Dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, terminologia, engenharia-de-software, pooling

O que significa pool de conexões tratando-se de Banco de Dados? O que esse conceito implica na prática? Qual a sua utilidade e importância no dia-a-dia? Segue abaixo uma definição na qual encontrei em minha pesquisa:

> Em engenharia de software, um pool de conexões é um cache de conexões
>   de banco de dados mantido de forma que as conexões possam ser
>   reutilizadas quando requisições futuras ao banco de dados forem
>   requeridas

Fonte : [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pool_de_conex%C3%B5es)

Answer (score 8):

Quando você precisa realizar qualquer operação sobre um banco de dados é primeiramente necessário estabelecer uma conexão com ele, tal conexão é geralmente feita utilizando o protocolo [TCP/IP](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP) e ela sempre vai incorrer custos para ser aberta e depois fechada. Esses custos são particularmente significativos em aplicações WEB onde você pode ter um fluxo de milhares de requisições constantes, e cada uma delas vai gerar a abertura e fechamento de uma nova conexão com o banco de dados. Uma técnica simples para evitar esse constante "abre-fecha" de conexões é manter um determinado número delas sempre abertas (um "pool" de conexões) e simplesmente resusá-las quando necessário, dessa forma você diminui tanto o gasto de recursos da máquina quanto o tempo de resposta da sua aplicação.